# Python: module name conflicts with upstream module name

Tags: python

I have a Python project which has a module (folder with **init**.py) which is named `gitlab`.
I also use the python-gitlab library in my project.

There seem to be a naming conflict:

In my gitlab module there is a action.py with the following content:

```
import gitlab # this should be import python-gitlab

# [...]
_gl = gitlab.Gitlab(url=gitlab_url, private_token=os.getenv('GIT_PASSWORD'))
```

This code does not work. The error is `NameError: name 'Gitlab' is not defined`

When I rename my module to `mygitlab` everything is fine.

So my question is: How can I import the "upstream" gitlab explizitly, as obviously the import statement the way i use it imports itself (?) and I have no `Gitlab` defined in my code.

Comment: You have the answer yourself. You can not use two packages/modules with the same name. So rename yours.

Answer (score 0):

I have only tried it partially, but there is probably a dirty trick that you could do, (not recommended at all of course, just out of curiosity):

```py
import sys
print(sys.path) # just to check that the path at index 0 is the one where your gitlab module is located
first_path = sys.path.pop(0)  # you remove it
import gitlab as gl  # you still have to change the name I think (that is the part I have not tried)
sys.path.insert(0, first_path)  # put it back
import gitlab  # import your module
```